# Negative Lookahead Regex greed (why is .*? too greedy)

Tags: python, regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble understanding the finer details of negative lookahead regular expressions.  After reading [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups), I thought I had a good summary of negative lookaheads when I found this description:

> `(?!REGEX_1)REGEX_2`
>
> Match only if `REGEX_1` does not match; after checking `REGEX_1`, the search for `REGEX_2` starts at the same position.

Hoping I understood the algorithm, I cooked up a two-sentence test insult; I wanted to find the sentence without a certain word.  Specifically...

> **Insult:** 'Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like a wet dog.'
>
> **Requirements**:
>
> - Test 1:  Return a sentence without 'ugly'.
> - Test 2:  Return a sentence without 'looks'.
> - Test 3:  Return a sentence without 'smells'.

I assigned the test words to `$arg`, and I used `(?:(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.))([A-Z].*?\.)` to implement the test.

- `(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.)` is a negative lookahead to reject a sentence with the test word
- `([A-Z].*?\.)` matches *at least* one sentence.

The critical piece seems to be in understanding where the regex engine starts matching after processing the negative lookahead.

**Expected Results**:

> - Test 1 ($arg = "ugly"): "And, she smells like a wet dog."
> - Test 2 ($arg = "looks"): "Yomama is ugly."
> - Test 3 ($arg = "smells"): "Yomama is ugly."

**Actual Results**:

> - Test 1 ($arg = "ugly"): "And, she smells like a wet dog." (Success)
> - Test 2 ($arg = "looks"): "Yomama is ugly." (Success)
> - Test 3 ($arg = "smells"): *Failed, no match*

At first I thought Test 3 failed because `([A-Z].*?\.)` was too greedy and matched both sentences; however, `(?:(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.))([A-Z][^\.]*?\.)` didn't work either.  Next I wondered whether there was a problem with the python negative lookahead implementation, but perl gave me exactly the same result.

Finally I found the solution, I had to reject periods in my `.*?` portion of the expressions by using `[^\.]*?`; so this regex works: `(?:(?![A-Z][^\.]*?$arg[^\.]*?\.))([A-Z][^\.]*?\.)`

### Question

However, I have another concern; "Yomama is ugly." does not have "smells" in it.  So, if `.*?` is supposed to be a non-greedy match, why can't I complete Test 3 with `(?:(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.))([A-Z].*?\.)`?

### EDIT

In light of @bvr's excellent suggestion to use `-Mre=debug`, I will consider this some more after work.  It certainly looks like Seth's description is accurate at this point.  What I learned so far is that negative lookahead expressions will match whenever possible, even if I put non-greedy `.*?` operators in the NLA.

---

### Python Implementation

```
import re

def test_re(arg, INSULTSTR):
    mm = re.search(r'''
        (?:                  # No grouping
        (?![A-Z].*?%s.*?\.)) # Negative zero-width
                             #     assertion: arg, followed by a period
        ([A-Z].*?\.)         # Match a capital letter followed by a period
        ''' % arg, INSULTSTR, re.VERBOSE)
    if mm is not None:
        print "neg-lookahead(%s) MATCHED: '%s'" % (arg, mm.group(1))
    else:
        print "Unable to match: neg-lookahead(%s) in '%s'" % (arg, INSULTSTR)


INSULT = 'Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like a wet dog.'
test_re('ugly', INSULT)
test_re('looks', INSULT)
test_re('smells', INSULT)
```

### Perl Implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub test_re {
    $arg    = $_[0];
    $INSULTSTR = $_[1];
    $INSULTSTR =~ /(?:(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.))([A-Z].*?\.)/;
    if ($1) {
        print "neg-lookahead($arg) MATCHED: '$1'\n";
    } else {
        print "Unable to match: neg-lookahead($arg) in '$INSULTSTR'\n";
    }
}

$INSULT = 'Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like a wet dog.';
test_re('ugly', $INSULT);
test_re('looks', $INSULT);
test_re('smells', $INSULT);
```

### Output

```
neg-lookahead(ugly) MATCHED: 'And, she smells like a wet dog.'
neg-lookahead(looks) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
Unable to match: neg-lookahead(smells) in 'Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like a wet dog.'
```

Comment: Other failures:  `test_re('Yomama',$INSULT);` and `test_re('And',$INSULT);`

Comment: @Mike: Yes, you are getting matches, but they are bad matches.  It is returning a sentence with the bad word in it.

Comment: Regarding your negative lookahead, what's the point of everything following `$arg`?  Seems to me that `(?![A-Z][^\.]*?$arg)` will fail just as well as what you have if `$arg` is encountered (failing being the desired behavior here).  But I don't know Perl or Python.

Comment: @harpo, I used `(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.)` in the negative lookahead because I want to reject a single sentence with `$arg` in it; however, I wanted to be 100% sure that I avoided match into the second sentence when possible.  Thus I explicitly matched the first period after `$arg`

Comment: I guess what I mean is, `(?![^\.]*?$arg)` should do it.

Comment: @harpo, that may be true, but my question is not so much what works (I almost got that right); it is why the original is too greedy in the face of `.*?` in the expressions.  I need to think through Seth's latest response to see if that answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub test_re {
    $arg    = $_[0];
    $INSULTSTR = $_[1];
    $INSULTSTR =~ /(?:^|\.\s*)(?:(?![^.]*?$arg[^.]*\.))([^.]*\.)/;
    if ($1) {
        print "neg-lookahead($arg) MATCHED: '$1'\n";
    } else {
        print "Unable to match: neg-lookahead($arg) in '$INSULTSTR'\n";
    }
}

$INSULT = 'Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like an wet dog.';
test_re('Yomama', $INSULT);
test_re('ugly', $INSULT);
test_re('looks', $INSULT);
test_re('And', $INSULT);
test_re('And,', $INSULT);
test_re('smells', $INSULT);
test_re('dog', $INSULT);
```

Results:

```
neg-lookahead(Yomama) MATCHED: 'And, she smells like an wet dog.'
neg-lookahead(ugly) MATCHED: 'And, she smells like an wet dog.'
neg-lookahead(looks) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
neg-lookahead(And) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
neg-lookahead(And,) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
neg-lookahead(smells) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
neg-lookahead(dog) MATCHED: 'Yomama is ugly.'
```

Comment: Seth, you certainly seem to have a better implementation; however, I'm trying to understand why my original code breaks WRT greediness.

Comment: My suspicion is that the problem is your asking for the second sentence to match by moving the pattern start location while still doing non-greedy matches.  The `.*?` is allowed to match `.` so there is no particular reason for the re engine to try to move the pattern start space.  If you change the `.*?` to `[^.]*` (greedy or not) the system will work (modula the first word match problem).

Comment: To help explain the problem try a pattern `[A-Z].*?smells.*?\.`. It matches the whole string. It should work with just `((?![A-Z][^\.]*?smells.*?\.)[A-Z].*?\.)`

Comment: @Mike: This might make what is happening more clear:  `` perl -e '$_="Yomama is ugly.  And, she smells like an wet dog."; $arg="smells"; print "Matched <$1>\n" if /([A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.)/;' `` The pattern start does not change and `.` is matched by `.*?`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're curious about what Perl is doing with a regex, you can run with the regex debugger:

```
perl -Dr -e '"A two. A one." =~ /(?![A-Z][^\.]*(?:two)[^\.]*\.)([A-Z][^\.]+\.)/; print ">$1<\n"'
```

which will generate much output for you to ponder.  You will need a Perl built with -DDEBUGGING.

Comment: Even perl without DEBUGGING can do it with `perl -Mre=debug -e ...`

Comment: @bvr, thank you for `-Mre=debug`; that option also allows me to run the script from-disk without `-e`, which is what I want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the regex engine will try as hard as possible to match `(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.)`, so with the "smells" case, it ends up matching the whole string. (The period in the middle is then included in one of the `.*?` constructs.) You should restrict the negative lookahead case to match only as much as the other case can:

Instead of:

```
(?:(?![A-Z].*?$arg.*?\.))([A-Z].*?\.)
```

Use:

```
(?:(?![A-Z][^.]*$arg[^.]*\.))([A-Z].*?\.)
```

Now, the negative lookahead cannot match more of the string than the other part can, since it must stop at the first period.